# Scrapy pull data from table rows

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to pull data from this page using Scrapy: https://www.interpol.int/notice/search/woa/1192802

The spider will crawl multiple pages but I have excluded the pagination code here to keep things simple. The problem is that the number of table rows that I want to scrape on each page can change each time.

So I need a way of scraping all the table data from the page no matter how many table rows it has.

First, I extracted all the table rows on the page. Then, I created a blank dictionary. Next, I tried to loop through each row and put it's cell data into the dictionary.

But it does not work and it is returning a blank file.

Any idea what's wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class Test1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test1'
    allowed_domains = ['interpol.int']
    start_urls = ['https://www.interpol.int/notice/search/woa/1192802']

    def parse(self, response):
        table_rows = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"col_gauche2_result_datasheet")]//tr').extract()
        data = {}
        for table_row in table_rows:
            data.update({response.xpath('//td[contains(@class, "col1")]/text()').extract(): response.css('//td[contains(@class, "col2")]/text()').extract()})
        yield data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this?

```
response.css('//td[contains(@class, "col2")]/text()').extract()
```

You are calling `css()` method but you are giving it a `xpath`

Anyways, here is the 100% working code, I have tested it.

```
table_rows = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"col_gauche2_result_datasheet")]//tr')
data = {}
for table_row in table_rows:
    data[table_row.xpath('td[@class="col1"]/text()').extract_first().strip()] = table_row.xpath('td[@class="col2 strong"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
yield data
```

**EDIT:**

To remove the characters like `\t\n\r` etc, use regex.

```
import re
your_string = re.sub('\\t|\\n|\\r', '', your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I Hope it will help you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test1'
    allowed_domains = ['interpol.int']
    start_urls = ['https://www.interpol.int/notice/search/woa/1192802']

    def parse(self, response):
        table_rows = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"col_gauche2_result_datasheet")]//tr')

        for table_row in table_rows:
            current_row = table_row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
            print(current_row[0] + current_row[1].strip())
```